# how to get verteces from VertexBuffer?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

i try to read a VertexBuffer . it returns an error of access exception . 
someone know how to read VertexBuffer like an array or how to convert it in something easyer to read  like an float array ?

Comment: mFa=new float[mFb.capacity()];
  mFb.get(mFa);